# Ruby - Beginner - Dividing using 2D Array

Tags: ruby

I can't figure out how to call upon the second piece of a 2D array.

```
array = [['dog',5], ['cat',10]]
num = 10

puts num / array[0,1]
```

Comment: That's not a 2D Array, there's no such thing in Ruby (there is a Matrix in the standard library but that's not an Array). That's just an array of arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the info, that's probably why I couldn't find anything searching for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [['dog',5], ['cat',10]]
num = 10

puts num / array[0][1] # 10/5 = 2
puts num / array[1][1] # 10/10 = 1
```